# Android - how to set theme values programmatically (dynamic theme values)

Tags: android, themes

Is that somehow possible? I want to use AppCompat and the new `primaryColor` and so on...

I don't want to create x themes but only one theme, and let the user set the colors in the settings.

I want to create a theme programmatically, is that somehow possible?

Btw., iterating all views of an `activity` or `fragment` and applying the custom colors would be possible, but I'm looking for a more clean way, using themes...

**EDIT**

What I want is, that I can define the colors in a theme like the following by code:

```
<style name="AppThemeDarkGreen" parent="AppThemeDefaultDark">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#4CAF50</item> <!-- 500 -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#388E3C</item><!-- 700 -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#C8E6C9</item><!-- 100 -->
</style>

<style name="AppThemeLightGreen" parent="AppThemeDefaultLight">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#4CAF50</item><!-- 500 -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#388E3C</item><!-- 700 -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#C8E6C9</item><!-- 100 -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most cleaner way is to create multiple themes according to the color, and allow the user to select the color to apply the theme.

Comment: I'm doing that right now... But this limits the themes... I would like to allow all combinations, not just only predefined ones...

Comment: All combination in what sense..How do you actually want it?

Comment: I added some code... I want to be able to allow selecting all possible themes (meaning all color combinations) by allowing the user to set 3 colors... Instead of selecting a few themes defined by myself

Comment: Check this link http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-set-custom-attributes-via.html if it could help you to find what you want to do.

Comment: actually, that's what I meant by iterating over views and then set colors programmatically... that's working of course, but that's no theme solution... I probably will have to stay with some predefined themes...